# Siri reading CFBundleName instead of CFBundleDisplayName when using INSendPaymentIntent

Tags: ios14, xcode12, siri, sirikit, cfbundledisplayname

We are facing some weird case when sending money via Siri, as it doesn't spell the app name defined in CFBundleDisplayName, so it does the one defined in CFBundleName on iOS > 14.0

First let me introduce the scenario to reproduce this.

- Have 2+ Apps installed that offers the Send Money functionality via Siri.
- Enable Siri via "Hey Siri" activation and ask to "Send Money"
- When Siri asks you what app do you want to use and spells their name, is using the one defined in CFBundleName, but the name displayed in the screen is the one defined in CFBundleDisplayName

We tried the same scenario on iOS13 and iOS12 and both spells the correct CFBundleDisplayName.
We didn't find any related change to this on iOS14 or Xcode12 changelogs, so not sure if this is a bug or what.

Changing the CFBundleName (which points to $(PRODUCT_NAME) right now) solves the issue, but that's a change that we don't want to do, since could add us some extra problems we don't expect.

Does anyone experienced this issue, and is there another way to fix it that is not changing the CFBundleName?

Thanks